# Creating a simple table diagram with arrow annotation

Tags: tables, diagrams

Many investent fund factsheets have a simple risk diagram as below, along with the annotation:

[image]

How would one recreate this in TeX? I though of using a table but perhaps some sort of tikz picture might be better. Being very new to TeX I am unsure of where to begin.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One possibility, using a TikZ's `matrix of math nodes`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{42,87,102}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[
  matrix of math nodes,
  row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
  nodes={
    draw,
    text width=1cm,
    align=center,
    minimum height=30pt
  }
  ] (mat)
  {
    1 & 2 & |[fill=myblue,font=\color{white}]|3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
  };
\draw[<->,>=latex]
  ([yshift=20pt]mat-1-1.north west) 
    node[anchor=north west,font=\scriptsize,inner xsep=0pt] {Lower Reward Potential}
    node[anchor=south west,font=\scriptsize,inner xsep=0pt] {Lower Risk}
    --
  ([yshift=20pt]mat-1-7.north east)
    node[anchor=north east,font=\scriptsize,inner xsep=0pt] {Higher Reward Potential}
    node[anchor=south east,font=\scriptsize,inner xsep=0pt] {Higer Risk}
  ;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing job. And exactly like my example. Many thanks

Answer (score 5):

Two TikZ-free options:

1. First, using some defined boxes and `\xleftrightarrow`:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{xcolor}
   \usepackage{mathtools}

   \definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{42,87,102}

   \newcommand\MyBox[2][white]{\fcolorbox{black}{#1}{\rule[-0.35cm]{0pt}{1cm}\makebox[1cm]{{#2}}}}

   \begin{document}

   \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr7cm+14\fboxsep+11\fboxrule\relax}
   {\scriptsize Lower Risk\hfill Higher Risk\par\vskip-1.5ex}
   $\xleftrightarrow{\hspace*{\dimexpr7cm+40pt\relax}}$\par\vskip-0.45ex
   {\scriptsize Lower Reward Potential\hfill Higher Reward Potential\par\medskip}

   \MyBox{1}%
   \hspace*{-0.5\fboxrule}\MyBox{2}%
   \hspace*{-0.5\fboxrule}\MyBox[myblue]{\textcolor{white}{3}}%
   \hspace*{-0.5\fboxrule}\MyBox{4}%
   \hspace*{-0.5\fboxrule}\MyBox{5}%
   \hspace*{-0.5\fboxrule}\MyBox{6}%
   \hspace*{-0.5\fboxrule}\MyBox{7}%
   \end{minipage}

   \end{document}
   ```

   [image]
2. Second, using a `tabular` and `\xleftrightarrow`:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
   \usepackage{array}
   \usepackage{mathtools}

   \definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{42,87,102}

   \begin{document}

   {
   \renewcommand\arraystretch{2}
   \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
   \begin{tabular}{*{7}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.5cm}}|}
   \multicolumn{7}{p{10.5cm}}{%
   {\scriptsize Lower Risk\hfill Higher Risk\par\vskip-3.5ex}
   $\xleftrightarrow{\hspace*{10.3cm}}$\par\vskip-0.45ex
   {\scriptsize Lower Reward Potential\hfill Higher Reward Potential\par\medskip}
   } \\[-3ex]
   \hline
   1 & 2 &\cellcolor{myblue}\textcolor{white}{3} & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
   \hline
   \end{tabular}
   }

   \end{document}
   ```

   [image]

Answer (score 2):

Another option: MetaPost, here in a LuaLaTeX program.

Here `N` gives the number of boxes, `n` the box which must be filled, `len` and `h` are the dimensions of a box. To be adapted at will.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
    \mplibsetformat{metafun}
    \mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\usepackage{xcolor}
    \definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{42,87,102}
\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}
n := 3; N := 7; len := 2cm; h := 1.5cm;
beginfig(1);
    path box; box = origin -- (len, 0) -- (len, h) -- (0, h) -- cycle;
    draw subpath (3, 4) of box;
    for i = 1 upto N:
        draw image(
            if i <> n:
                draw subpath (0, 3) of box;
                label("{\huge" & decimal i & "}", center box);
            else:
                fill box withcolor \mpcolor{myblue}; draw box;
                label("{\huge" & decimal i & "}", center box) withcolor white;
            fi) shifted ((i-1)*len, 0);
    endfor;
    pair arrow_offset; arrow_offset := (0, h + \mpdim{1.5\bigskipamount});
    path arrow; arrow = (origin -- N*len*right) shifted arrow_offset; drawdblarrow arrow;
    labeloffset := 0bp; pair offset; offset = (0, 4bp);
    label.lrt("Lower Reward Potential", point 0 of arrow) shifted -offset;
    label.llft("Higher Reward Potential", point 1 of arrow) shifted -offset;
    label.urt("Lower Risk", point 0 of arrow) shifted offset;
    label.ulft("Higher Risk", point 1 of arrow) shifted offset;  
    setbounds currentpicture to boundingbox currentpicture enlarged 3mm;
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

[image]